# Archiving a folder using react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, zip

How can I archive a folder using react native expo? I have tried using the package `react-native-zip-archive` but it seems it doesn't work with expo.
Is it possible to create a .zip file out of a folder, then later unzipping it, using expo?

Answer (score 0):

Expo doesn't support react-native-zip-archive at the moment. You need to use expo prebuild to add react native features that are not supported on expo to your app and still be able to use expo. You can get more information via https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/

Comment: it is a comment. not an answer

Comment: Thanks for the observation, corrected